# Representing a co-Heyting algebra as a lattice of semialgebraic sets in a real algebraic variety

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, real-algebraic-geometry

Every co-Heyting algebra can be embedded in the co-Heyting algebra of closed sets in a spectral space.  (Co-heyting algebras are the order-theoretic duals of Heyting algebras.)  Now I am told the following without a proof.

> Every finite co-Heyting algebra can be embedded in the co-Heyting algebra of semialgebraic sets in a real algebraic variety.

Why is this true?  The paper that claims this has no reference for this fact, and I am lost.  (I am looking for an elementary answer since I know virtually nothing about real geometry.)

Answer (score 0):

A finite distributive lattice can be embedded in a finite power set (Birkhoff representation), which is the lattice of semialgebraic sets of a finite set of points.